# JUnit and Spring - code coverage % is wrong when using multiple Threads in test

Tags: spring, multithreading, junit, code-coverage, eclemma

We tried to use a couple of code-coverage plugins for our spring project (EclEmma,Clover).

Both are providing wrong results regarding the coverage %.

The tests are using Spring's taskExecutor (thread pool).

All the code that the task executors threads executes does not count as covered.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of such code and test for it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. It seems that test coverage doesnt work well with multithreads.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34633675)